# How do I pass delegated OAuth2 permissions to my .NET application hosted in Azure Web Service?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, blazor, azure-web-app-service

I have a .NET (Blazor) application running in Azure App Service, using Azure Active Directory for authentication. I'd like to interface with various Azure APIs (e.g. Defender) as the signed in user. I can use the `X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN` and `X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN` headers to get the associated tokens, but when I examine the access token provided with jwt.ms the "scp" field is: `email Files.ReadWrite openid profile User.Read User.Read.All` and the token is not valid for the services I am attempting to use.

I have granted the MTP `AdvancedHunting.Read` delegated permission in the application registration but it doesn't seem to be passed to the application, as examined in jwt.ms. I need this permission to interface with the Defender ATP API *as the user* at https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com

It appears [I can use Resource Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-user?tabs=azure-resource-explorer) to edit the scope for the App Service, but attempting to add anything related to what I'm looking for appears to crash the app.

Edit: In further testing it appears that any API permissions assigned related to Graph pass through fine, so I can pass https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/runHuntingQuery, but the options are limited beyond that. The question then boils down to how can I use my existing token to get a token with the appropriate permissions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.